# Book recommendation of Complex Variables (before Complex Analysis).

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm an engineering student but I self-study pure mathematics. I am looking for a Complex Variables Introduction book (to study before complex analysis). I have the Brown and Churchill book but I was told that's for engineers and physicist mostly, not for mathematicians. I also looked for Fisher and Flanigan, but they don't seem to have as many topics as Brown. I wonder which book is best for the subject or if one of the two previously mentioned will do to master most of the topics of complex variables as a mathematician. Thanks.

Comment: Ahlfors is nice if you want rigor, Marsden is pretty decent w/ worked out examples. I haven't tried either of the books you've mentioned.

Comment: David Ullrich's *Complex made simple* looks very well written, although it's a bit pricey.

Answer (score 0):

Stein and Shakarchi is pretty good, and there's a free pdf online: https://www.fing.edu.uy/~cerminar/Complex_Analysis.pdf.